# Apply different CSS style to :after element on another page?

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation, where I use:

```
.header-link:after { .... background-color: red; .....}
```

I have this in my global scss stylesheet, affecting all pages.

On one specific page I need this :after element to be different color. When I use the same code and put it in the page specific css style sheet:

```
.header-link:after { .... background-color: white; .....}
```

It naturally rewrites the original one and all pages become this new color. As the page specific CSS stylesheet is imported after the global css stylesheet.

How do I apply this new background color, so that only the specific page is affected and it's not rewriting the original one on other pages?

Comment: The strongest way i would say, set page name as a class in the html/body tag, then use hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use an ID on the page that goes against your rules ?

Normal Css

```
.header-link:after { .... background-color: red; .....}
```

Specific Page, but with an id="pageHeaderWhite" on  ou  per example, and then create the custom rule.

```
#pageHeaderWhite .header-link:after { .... background-color: white; .....}
```

Your CSS specificity triggers because a rule with an ID is stronger than a rule with only class: selector.

Hope it works!

Answer (score -1):

1. apply different classes
2. use another way of targeting this element - by ID